# Rename multiple nics using a CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv

I cannot seem to figure this array/loop combination out.  I am looking to run a script that will obtain all active NICs and then rename them based on a CSV file.  Afterwards, I create a NIC Team and utilize the CSV file again to setup the static networking information.

I obtain all active nics using:

```
$Adapter = Get-NetAdapter | where {$_.status -eq "up"}
```

The CSV file headings is in the following form:

```
host    newname   ipaddress   subnet    gateway    dns
```

The `newname` column has the value of `admin1a;admin1b`.

Here is an example that works but produces errors:

```
Foreach ($entry in $DC1_NICS) {
    $NewName = $entry.NewName.split(";")
    Foreach ($item in $NewName) {
        Foreach ($nic in $Adapter) {
            Rename-NetAdapter -Name $Nic.Name -NewName $item
        }
    }
}
```

So, I have two names that I can split, `admin1a` and `admin1b` but I cannot seem to get the NICs to be named appropriately, either only one NIC gets renamed or both do and then there are additional errors.

Comment: Show us the entire CSV file, or at least a sample.

Comment: @WalterMitty Shouldn't matter what the entire CSV looks like. The issue isn't with his CSV, it's with his ForEach loops. Answer coming shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your nested `ForEach` loops, because it takes the first name, then for each NIC it tries to name that NIC to the name, and then it moves to the second name, and for each NIC it tries to name it that, so say you have a server with 2 NICs, and your CSV gives the names Admin1 and Admin2. It loops through the names, and run the internal loop each time:

Rename NIC1 to Admin1
Rename NIC2 to Admin1

Then it does the same thing for the second name, Admin2:

Rename NIC1 to Admin2
Rename NIC2 to Admin2

So that's the crux of the problem... you need to iterate through both NICs, and new names. In this case you need a `For` loop. Base it off of the number of NICs, and let's hope you have enough names specified in your CSV.

```
Foreach ($entry in $DC1_NICS) {
    $Adapter = Get-NetAdapter | where {$_.status -eq "up"}
    $NewName = $entry.NewName.split(";")
    For($i = 0;$i -lt $Adapter.count;$i++){
        Rename-NetAdapter -Name $Adapter[$i].Name -NewName $NewName[$i]
    }
}
```

So the first NIC gets the first name, and the second NIC gets the second name, and if there's a third NIC it will get the third name. This doesn't solve the fact that it looks like this is designed for multiple servers, and you are only performing the function on the host server, but it solves the issue of the problem that you specifically asked about.

Comment: This does appear to work but the end count of $i is 3, so it iterates through 3 times instead of just two thus sending an error on the third run since there is nothing for the name variable.  I suspect the $i -le $adapter.count should have prevent another entrance into the for loop is that correct?

Comment: Ah, right, sorry. That should be `-lt` and not `-le`. I will update the answer in a moment to reflect that. (`-lt` is "Less Than", while `-le` is "Less Than, or Equal To" so this will stop when it become equal rather than running one last time when it is equal)